# Tensorflow serving performance slow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a model (based on Mask_RCNN) which I have exported to a servable. I can run it with tf serving in a docker container locally on my Macbook pro and using the json API it will respond in 15-20s, which is not fast but I didn't really expect it to be.

I've tried to serve it on various AWS machines based off the DLAMI and also tried some Ubuntu AMIs specifically using a p2.xlarge with a gpu, 4vcpus and 61GB of RAM. When I do this the same model responds in about 90s. The configurations are identical since I've built a docker image with the model inside it.

I also get a timeout using the AWS example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-tfserving.html

Has anyone else experienced anything similar to this or have any ideas on how I can fix or isolate the problem?

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/311) and let us know if it helps, Thanks.